# Flow Router get Current Router serverside

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I want to save the entry point of a user on my side. So here is my solution

```
Meteor.onConnection(function(conn) {
console.log(conn.clientAddress);
console.log(FlowRouter.getRouteName());
var id = database.insert({
    page: "page",
    ip: conn.clientAddress,
    enterdPagedAt: new Date(), 
    isActive: true
});
```

});

as u can see, under page, i want to save the route where he entered. So how can i get the current route on the server using flow router ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Meteor Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/routing.html#analytics) comes a tip:

> It’s common to want to know which pages of your app are most commonly visited, and where users are coming from. You can read about how to set up Flow Router based analytics in the [Deployment Guide](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#analytics).

Even if you don't want to use a third-party analytics service, the [okgrow:analytics package](https://atmospherejs.com/okgrow/analytics) they refer to should have the info you need buried in [its code](https://github.com/okgrow/analytics/).

Comment: See https://github.com/okgrow/analytics/blob/master/client/flow-router.js , which does use global flow triggers that I had proposed in my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flow Router is a *client-side* router. You have to make the client send it's current route to the server if you want to have that info on the server. A [global Flow Router trigger](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#defining-triggers-globally) could do the trick.

Caveat: It's been a while since I last developed using Meteor. Flow router wasn't even around back then.